# Given an embedding $h:D^n \to S^n$, is the closure of the complement $S^n-h(D^n)$ homeomorphic to $D^n$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Given an embedding $h:D^n  \to S^n$, is the closure of the complement $S^n-h(D^n)$ homeomorphic to $D^n$?

What I know about this is:

$h$ restricts to an embedding $h:S^{n-1} \to S^n$, and the generalized Jordan's curve theorem implies that $S^n-h(S^{n-1})$ has two components, having common boundary $h(S^{n-1})$. In the above case, we also know that the closure of such one component is homeomorphic to $D^n$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is it a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, this is a counter example. More examples of this type can be found for instance in [Geometric topology of 3-manifolds](https://bookstore.ams.org/coll-40) by Bing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you are asking about holds for $n=2$ (Schoenflies theorem) and it fails in higher dimensions.

Schoenflies theorem for $S^2$ states that every Jordan curve $J$ in $S^2$ is "standard", i.e. there exists a homeomorphisms $S^2\to S^2$ sending $J$ to a round circle. From this, it follows that the closure of each component of $S^2-J$ is homeomorphic to the closed 2-disk.

However, it fails in higher dimensions. The first example was constructed by J.W.Alexander and is called [Alexander horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere). It is a subset $\Sigma\subset S^3$ homeomorphic to $S^2$, such that the closure of one component $C_1$ of $S^3-\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to the closed 3-ball, while the closure of the other component ($C_2$) is not. In fact $C_2$ is not even homeomorphic to $R^3$ as it is not simply connected.